# Express form post request handling middleware returns RangeError

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have a form from which i have to get my data. I'm using ejs templates. 
My "/" route renders "main" view and I have a middleware to work with my data coming from the form, but it returns an error of "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

My Express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const validator = require('validator.js');

app.set('view engine','ejs');

const urlEncodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('main');
});

app.post('/register', urlEncodedParser, (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My form:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name='name' class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name='surname' class="form-control">
        <input type="number" name='age' class="form-control">
        <input type="email" name='email' class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name='password' class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name='confirm' class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="OKAY">
</form>
```

The full error which I get:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:202:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:97:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:101:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\express+mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlEncodedParser` is making issue it should not be in middleware :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const validator = require('validator.js');

    app.set('view engine','ejs');

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
        res.render('main');
    });

    app.post('/register', (req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.body);
    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The cause of your issue is that you are passing in an app as middleware to your request handler. Specifically here:

```
const urlEncodedParser = app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.post('/register', urlEncodedParser, (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

`urlEncodedParser` is just another reference to your app. Thus you are stuck in a infinite loop where the route calls `urlEncodedParser` that flows down to your route which in turn calls `urlEncodedParser` and so on until you pop the stack.